# How to map an object to contain a Map in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate-mapping

Let's say I have a table '`Team`' and another table '`Team Members`'.  Team Member has a foreign key to Team.

Ideally, I would want hibernate to map my java objects such that, `Team` class would have a Map of T`eam Members`. The key of the map is the name of the team member, and value is the `TeamMember` object.

So I would want my Team class to look like this:

```
public class Team {
    private Map<String, TeamMember> _teamMembers;
}
```

How do I map in my hibernate xml mapping file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need `<map>` and set the index column to the column of the name property

```
<map name="teamMembers">
  <key column="team_id" />
  <index column="NameColumn" />
  <one-to-many class="TeamMember" />
</map>
```